# How to use less code for this situation

Tags: c#

Currently, I have code like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int whichClass = 0;
        if (whichClass == 0)
        {
            //repeat code
            TestAbstract clTest = new ClassA();
            clTest.MainFunc();
        }
        else if (whichClass == 1)
        {
            //repeat code
            TestAbstract clTest = new ClassB();
            clTest.MainFunc();
        }
        else if (whichClass == 10)
        {
            //repeat code
            TestAbstract clTest = new ClassX();
            clTest.MainFunc();
        }
    }
```

As you see, I have to write code 3 times for initial and call function at 3 different classes.

What I want is we just call 1 time with dynamic class. How can it is possible?

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
        int whichClass = 0;
        TestAbstract clTest = null;
        if (whichClass == 0)
            clTest = new ClassA();
        else if (whichClass == 1)
             clTest = new ClassB();
        else if (whichClass == 10)
             clTest = new ClassX();
        if(clTest != null)
             clTest.MainFunc();
```

}

Comment: yes. Thank you. I'll try to apply this.

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could have a `Dictionary<int, Type>`, or a `Dictionary<int, Func<TestAbstract>`:

```
var typeMapping = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    { 0, typeof(ClassA) },
    { 1, typeof(ClassB) },
    { 10, typeof(ClassX) }
};

...
Type type;
if (typeMapping.TryGetValue(whichClass, out type))
{
    TestAbstract test = (TestAbstract) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    test.MainFunc();
}
```

Using a `Func<TestAbstract>` would give more flexibility for how you created the `TestAbstract` instances, and provide more compile-time type safety, but be more long-winded:

```
var factoryMapping = new Dictionary<int, Func<TestAbstract>>
{
    { 0, () => new ClassA() },
    { 1, () => new ClassB() },
    { 10, () => new ClassX() }
};

...
Func<TestAbstract> factory;
if (factoryMapping.TryGetValue(whichClass, out factory))
{
    TestAbstract test = factory();
    test.MainFunc();
}
```

It's not clear where the integer values are coming from, by the way - you might want an enum for that. Heck, the enum names could even be the names of the types:

```
TestClass whichClass = TestClass.ClassA;

...

Type type = Type.GetType("SomeNamespace." + whichClass);
TestAbstract test = (TestAbstract) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Damn it, Skeet... you edited in the second half of the post just as I was writing out that version. +1

Comment: yes. You definately help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Factory class, which would return the object according to the parameter 
passed.

```
public static TestAbstractFactory
{
  public static TestAbstract GetTestAbstract(int whichClass)
  { 
      switch(whichClass)
      {
      case 0:
        return new ClassA();
      case 1:
        return new ClassB();
      case 10:
        return new ClassX();
      default: 
        return null;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. Thank you. I'll try to apply this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ClassA to C derives from TestAbstract and assuming MainFunc is a virtual method on TestAbstract, you can use the following code

```
static void Main()
{
    int whichClass = 0; // 0 to 2
    Type type = new[] { typeof(ClassA), typeof(ClassB), typeof(ClassC) } [ whichClass ];        
    TestAbstract clTest = (TestAbstract) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    clTest.MainFunc();
}
```

Comment: yes. Thank you. I'll try to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
  int whichClass = 0;
  TestAbstract clTest ;
  if (whichClass == 0)
  {
   //repeat code
   clTest = new ClassA();
  }
  else if (whichClass == 1)
  {
   //repeat code
   clTest = new ClassB();
  }
 else if (whichClass == 10)
 {
  //repeat code
   clTest = new ClassX();        
  }

  clTest.MainFunc();
}
```

Comment: yes. Thanks, but I've already knew about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

> static void Main()
>
> ```
> {
>     int whichClass = 0;
>     TestAbstract clTest;
>
>     if (whichClass == 0)
>     {
>         //repeat code
>          clTest = new ClassA();
>     }
>     else if (whichClass == 1)
>     {
>         //repeat code
>         clTest = new ClassB();
>     }
>     else if (whichClass == 10)
>     {
>         //repeat code
>         clTest = new ClassX();
>     }
>     if(clTest != null)
>         clTest.MainFunc();
> }
> ```

Comment: yes. Thanks, but I've already knew about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflection.

```
string whichClass = "className";
Type t = Type.GetType(whichClass);
TestAbstract o = (TestAbstract)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
o.MainFunc();
```

Comment: yes. Thank you. I'll try to apply this.